# Maintain links to certain pages after renaming

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink, content-management-system

I am working on a CMS with php, mysql.

I store my page information in mysql database: table `pages` columns(`id`, `title`, `title_url`, `published_time`, ... )

What is the best solution to maintain links to certain pages if a customer renames them? (`title` and `title_url` change after renaming)

Example:
link to page -> `homepage/gold_news`
Customer renames `gold_news` to `gold_price_news` (now `title_url` in database is `gold_price_news`)
and old link to page -> `homepage/gold_news`, which doesn't work anymore.

Comment: You need to create your URLs based on title_url

Answer (score 1):

You you can add a new field in the table called "redirectId"

thenn create a new row in the table with the new url (inserted id:999)

and in the old row you will set the value redirectId=999

when old urls are requested, redirect them to the new url using the http 301 status code

Answer (score 1):

I would use a combination of .htaccess (mod rewrite) and the id and title fields in your DB.

Firstly, all page URLs/links should be in the form:

```
yourdomain.com/page/idnumber/pagetitle
```

With 'pagetitle' being there for plain text readability purposes and serving no purpose (merely being the title value from your DB), and the id being the actual reference to the page (the id for that page in your DB).

As you are using the id as an anchoring reference to the page, it doesnt matter if the user changes the page title/url in the DB, as the record's id is fixed.

Your .htaccess should then contain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/(.*)/?$ yourdomainpath/pagehandler.php?pageid==$1 [NC,L]
```

What this does is take a URL of the type specified above (e.g. yourdomain.com/page/1/my page/), and route that request to the php script which loads the content, e.g. yourdomainpath/pagehandler.php, passing the id as the GET variable 'pageid'.

The user sees a nice clean URL, which .htaccess then 'redirects' behind the scenes to your script, which takes the id out of the URL and gets the content linked to this id in your DB. As this is id based, users can have free realm to change other fields' content in the DB without any knowck on effect. A nice, clean solution.